How do Blok and the other astronaut do a spacewalk to repair the ship? Didn’t they already land?
I’m a little confused by Europa Report. How do Blok and the other astronaut do a spacewalk to repair the ship? It shows them in space repairing it. But didn’t they already land? They are already on the surface of Europa, drilling. How’d they end up back in outer space?

Its a flashback.
The EVA is after a solar storm that hit six months after launch.
They go into orbit after 20 months (roughly where the film starts with them landing), the atmosphere (pun) amongst the crew is portrayed as very different by the time they land, and the flashback shows why.
Wiki doesn't mention this, but the following link does:





In the 90s they always put the date and location on the screen at scene switches (usually with a cheesy typewriter effect). I really wish they'd continue doing that.

@AndreKR i think not only 90s too; if they had more consideration for the viewer I think they would have done that (not only that, the story telling was flawed, the time jumping felt like they were afraid that a linear timeline would be too boring). Some aspects I enjoyed but quite a few things soured the milk as it were.
